# Why is thrown UnexpectedRollbackException for a RuntimeException?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

In Spring Framework, about Transactions *by default*:

- When a `RuntimeException` (**unchecked** type) is thrown then is triggered automatically a *Rollback* process
- When an `Exception` (**checked** type) is thrown then is **not** triggered a *Rollback* process.

Until here it is very clear. Now see the following code:

```
@Transactional //declared on class level, but copy here to avoid confusions
public void createProcessV2(Ciencia ciencia, Cientifico cientifico) {

    try {
        cienciaService.save(ciencia);
        businessService.doBusiness();
        cientificoService.save(cientifico);
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(" createProcess V2...");
        System.out.println("  Catching and Handling Throwable");
        System.out.println("   Type   : " + t.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Message: " + t.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Where `cienciaService` and `cientificoService` are `@Service` classes and they have access to a DB through their respective `@Repository` dependencies. Now about `businessService` can be any of the following:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Profile("exception-checked-try-catch-non")
class BusinessExceptionV2ServiceImpl implements BusinessService {

    @Override
    public void doBusiness() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(" doBusiness ...");
        System.out.println("  Throwing Exception ...");
        throw new BusinessException("It is a Business Exception");
    }

}
```

or

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Profile("exception-unchecked-try-catch-non")
class BusinessRuntimeExceptionV2ServiceImpl implements BusinessService {

    @Override
    public void doBusiness() {
        System.out.println(" doBusiness ...");
        System.out.println("  Throwing RuntimeException ...");
        throw new BusinessRuntimeException("It is a Business Runtime Exception");
    }

}
```

Both `@Service` classes are based on `@Profile`, to only enable one at runtime, and they don't have a `@Repository` access, and they thrown a custom exception as *checked* and *unchecked* according the case.

Finally in the `Main` class exists:

```
ProcessService processService = ctx.getBean(ProcessService.class);

try {
    Ciencia ciencia = CienciaFactory.createCienciaWithId10();
    Cientifico cientifico = CientificoFactory.createCientificoWithId14(ciencia);
    processService.createProcessV2(ciencia, cientifico);
}
catch(Throwable t) {
    System.out.println(" Main...");
    System.out.println("  Catching and Handling Throwable");
    System.out.println("   Type   : " + t.getClass());
    System.out.println("   Message: " + t.getMessage());
}
```

When the app is executed with the *exception-checked-try-catch-non* profile it happens

```
cienciaService.save(ciencia); //run 
businessService.doBusiness(); //run and is thrown a **checked** exception
cientificoService.save(cientifico); //never executed
```

and the output is

```
 doBusiness ...
  Throwing Exception ...
 createProcess V2...
  Catching and Handling Throwable
   Type   : class com.manuel.jordan.exception.BusinessException
   Message: It is a Business Exception
```

Because `cienciaService.save(ciencia)` was executed and did **not** happen a *Rollback* because `businessService.doBusiness()` thrown an *checked* exception: then the DB passes to a not valid integrity state. It is expected - of course it is not a valid scenario but for academic purposes has sense use this scenario. Therefore until here it is ok.

When the app is executed with the *exception-unchecked-try-catch-non* profile it happens

```
cienciaService.save(ciencia); //run 
businessService.doBusiness(); //run and is thrown an **unchecked** exception
cientificoService.save(cientifico); //never executed
```

and the output is

```
 doBusiness ...
  Throwing RuntimeException ...
 createProcess V2...
  Catching and Handling Throwable
   Type   : class com.manuel.jordan.exception.BusinessRuntimeException
   Message: It is a Business Runtime Exception
 Main...
  Catching and Handling Throwable
   Type   : class org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException
   Message: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

Because `cienciaService.save(ciencia)` was executed and happened a *Rollback* because `businessService.doBusiness()` thrown an ***un**checked* exception: then the DB does **not** pass to a not valid integrity state. It is expected - it is the desirable scenario.

**But** Why was thrown `UnexpectedRollbackException`?. The rollback is expected because an unchecked exception was thrown. This situation generates some failures in some `@Test` methods and if the `Main` class does not have that *try/catch* block it ends in error

**Note**

This situation happens even with:

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackFor = BusinessRuntimeException.class)
public void createProcessV2(Ciencia ciencia, Cientifico cientifico) {
   ...
```

and (just in case)

```
@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = BusinessRuntimeException.class)
public void createProcessV2(Ciencia ciencia, Cientifico cientifico) {
   ...
```

**Update**

About the *Proxy* with *Spring's Transaction* support, if is used:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void createProcessV2(Ciencia ciencia, Cientifico cientifico) throws Throwable {

    try {
        cienciaService.save(ciencia);
        businessService.doBusiness();
        cientificoService.save(cientifico);
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(" createProcess V2...");
        System.out.println("  Catching and Handling Throwable");
        System.out.println("   Type   : " + t.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Message: " + t.getMessage());
        throw t; // <--------
    }

}
```

From above observe the addition of the `throw t;` sentence in *catch*  the block. Therefore the output is:

```
 doBusiness ...
  Throwing RuntimeException ...
 createProcess V2...
  Catching and Handling Throwable
   Type   : class com.manuel.jordan.exception.BusinessRuntimeException
   Message: It is a Business Runtime Exception
 Main...
  Catching and Handling Throwable
   Type   : class com.manuel.jordan.exception.BusinessRuntimeException
   Message: It is a Business Runtime Exception
```

Therefore now all is solved and the *Rollback* works fine for the 2 tables in the DB. Now due **academic** purposes, observe now the following:

```
@Override
@Transactional(noRollbackFor={BusinessRuntimeException.class}) // <--------
public void createProcessV2(Ciencia ciencia, Cientifico cientifico) throws Throwable {

    try {
        cienciaService.save(ciencia);
        businessService.doBusiness();
        cientificoService.save(cientifico);
    }
    catch(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(" createProcess V2...");
        System.out.println("  Catching and Handling Throwable");
        System.out.println("   Type   : " + t.getClass());
        System.out.println("   Message: " + t.getMessage());
        throw t; // <--------
    }

}
```

The goal is that even if the `BusinessRuntimeException` is re-thrown and therefore it must be detected by the *Proxy* with *Spring's Transaction* support, the *Rollback* must be **not** applied due the `noRollbackFor={BusinessRuntimeException.class}` declaration. Therefore the `cienciaService.save(ciencia)` execution must remain in the DB and left the DB with a *not* valid integrity state. Remember it is an academic purpose.

But

```
 doBusiness ...
  Throwing RuntimeException ...
 createProcess V2...
  Catching and Handling Throwable
   Type   : class com.manuel.jordan.exception.BusinessRuntimeException
   Message: It is a Business Runtime Exception
Jun 26, 2023 9:00:09 AM org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport completeTransactionAfterThrowing
SEVERE: Application exception overridden by commit exception
com.manuel.jordan.exception.BusinessRuntimeException: It is a Business Runtime Exception
    at com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.BusinessRuntimeExceptionV2ServiceImpl.doBusiness(BusinessRuntimeExceptionV2ServiceImpl.java:24)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy50.doBusiness(Unknown Source)
    at com.manuel.jordan.service.impl.ProcessServiceImpl.createProcessV2(ProcessServiceImpl.java:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218)
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy54.createProcessV2(Unknown Source)
    at com.manuel.jordan.main.Main.main(Main.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

 Main...
  Catching and Handling Throwable
   Type   : class org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException
   Message: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only
```

Why does `noRollbackFor` no work as expected?

and arises:

```
SEVERE: Application exception overridden by commit exception
```

Comment: It is because you are catching and swallow the exception. Transaction management thus doesn't see this exception and will try to commit, this isn't possible because the transaction is already marked for rollback. Hence the exception. Rule of thumb never catch and swallow an exception.

Comment: Therefore should be _re-throw_ from the _try/catch_ block, right? There are some projects that use the `try/catch` block to handle the flow process and can't be edited.

Comment: _Transaction management thus doesn't see this exception and will try to commit_ - it is about the Proxy with the Transaction support.

Comment: THe proxy doesn't see the exception because you catch it, hence for the transaction management it is unexpected because there was no exception.

Comment: @M.Deinum see the _updated_ section.

Comment: @M.Deinum about "_this isn't possible because the transaction is already marked for rollback_" - By whom is marked if the _Proxy_ (therefore the _Transaction Management_) is not aware about the _caught_ and _swallowed_ exception?

Comment: You have multiple `@Transactional` annotations, each of those creates a proxy. Although it detects that it isn't the most outer method being called upon the throwing of the `RuntimeException` your `BusinessRuntimeExceptionV2ServiceImpl` marks the transaction for rollback only (while not yet rolling back the whole transaction). The configuration belongs on the method/transaction that is actually handling that exception.

Comment: Your explanation has sense, Just in case: a `@Service` as process using multiple `@Service`  is valid, and because each nested `@Service` can be called directly by a `@Controller`, therefore is valid that them use `@Transactional` too. It with the purpose to keep the logic about of the most outer method that defines the main settings of transactions